# Why does this auto command to disable hlsearch not work?

Tags: gvim, autocmd, highlight

I like having `hlsearch` on, but find it annoying in insert mode. So I tried doing the following autocommand to disable it whenever I enter insert mode:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * nohlsearch
```

For whatever reason, this does not work. So that I could verify this wasn't a problem with my `.vimrc`, I tried this after launching vim with

```
gvim -u NORC
```

Any help debugging this would be greatly appreciated! I'm using gvim version 7.4.1023 on windows.

Comment: Did you gave a colon after * symbol, like `* :no`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:nohlsearch` doesn't work inside an autocommand, as explained in `:help :nohlsearch`:

> Stop the highlighting for the 'hlsearch' option.  It is automatically turned back on when using a search command, or setting the 'hlsearch' option. **This command doesn't work in an autocommand, because the highlighting state is saved and restored when executing autocommands. Same thing for when invoking a user function.**

In [vim-cool](https://github.com/romainl/vim-cool), I worked around that "issue" by using `:set nohlsearch`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I can't believe the answer was *right there* in help, and I missed it. Also, thanks for the plugin recommendation!